# ESTA visa marriage

Tags: esta, weddings

If you get married during your ESTA visa time, does that mean you can stay with your husband permanently? because I'm going to the U.S on an ESTA visa to be with my boyfriend and we want to get married but don't want to go through the process of the fiance visa so is it permitted we can get married during that time?

Comment: You have already asked three very similar questions, apparently ignoring all feedback. Please edit your earlier questions if you have details to add, stop talking about “ESTA visa” (makes no sense) and wait if someone can provide a full answer.

Comment: Still off topic for this site.  It's a question for expatriates.SE.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Engagement after entering the US with an ESTA](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51425/engagement-after-entering-the-us-with-an-esta)

Answer (score 2):

This is important.

- **Getting married does not give you any right to stay in the US, irrespective of whether your spouse is a legal immigrant, permanent resident or citizen of the US**
- **Getting married does not allow you to break visa rules.** If your visa waiver only allows you to stay in the US for ninety days, you must leave after ninety days, even if you get married in the US

Even if you have a valid ESTA and qualify for a Visa Waiver, an immigration officer may deny you entry if he thinks you are coming to the US with the intention of staying permanently.

I believe there is nothing (in terms of immigration restrictions) preventing you from getting married while in the US, but to re-iterate again **you still have to leave when your visa waiver period is finished**. Be aware that some states have residency restrictions on getting married, which may affect your plans.

If you want to stay in the US with your boyfriend/husband you **must** apply for the appropriate visa. Questions about that belong on the [Expatriates site](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com), not here